# How do Keygens function?

Tags: key-generator

A keying algorithm used to register software and games.  Let's say there is no server-side verification to get in the way...

I would like to know how these can be replicated in C Code so I can have a better understanding of creating my own keygens.

I'm currently a student learning Reverse Engineering and I am trying to reverse crackmes in order to build a keygen for the software.

---

1. What are the steps to creating my own keygen that I can debug and crack?
2. Are all keygens basically a sum of ASCII numbers?
3. Are there different variants of keygens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key generators you're thinking of work very similar to Cryptographic hash functions and often (if not checking with an online authority) verify against some files or checksums and the software just stops execution if the hash/key wasn't found or entered correctly.

You're getting your terminology mixed up speaking about "ASCII Numbers". Any data on a computer can be converted to numbers, and if chosen to convert blocks of 8 bits to numbers between 0-255 you'll always find a corresponding ASCII character. Often you will actually find that keys are encoded in hex, characters from 0-9 and A-F using 4 bits per character.

And, there are *many*.